# Access to repetitive tags in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mp3, html5-audio

So I've got this piece of HTML (it's mp3 player):

```
<div id="player-body_0" class="player-body">
    <audio id="player_0" class="player">
        <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2543.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <div id="audio-player_0" class="audio-player">
        <div id="controls_0" class="controls">
            <i id="play_0" class="fa fa-play play"></i>
            <span id="start-time_0" class="time start-time">00:00</span>
            <div id="progressbar_0" class="progressbar"></div>
            <span id="time_0" class="time">00:00</span>
            <i id="mute_0" class="fa fa-volume-up mute" onclick=""></i>
            <div id="volume_0" class="volume"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

code is automatically generated, so I could have 30+ players like this all on the same website. Ids in tags of course will increment in every next player-body.
How could I manage all this players with generic methods in jQuery?
To manage player mute button I could have something like this:

```
var mute_button = $('.mute'); 
var player = document.getElementById('player_0');

mute_button.click(function() {
    $(this); //clicked mute button
    //how to easily access proper audio tag without using its id?
});
```

But how in above function I could access audio player tag without using its id? As I said I want methods to be generic I can't just repeat them like 30+ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `.mute` icon... Lookup for the [parent matching](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) the `.player-body`...  Then lookdown, using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), for the `<audio>` tag using the `.player` class...

You now have the target element!

Then simply [mute it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/muted)... Okay... You need the DOM element, not the jQuery object. But you have it using `[0]` against a jQuery object because the DOM element is the first property.

Concretely, it's a one liner:

```
$('.mute').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents(".player-body").find(".player")[0].muted = true;
});
```

That is what's called "traversing" DOM elements...
You just have to know [*a couple*](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) jQuery methods to navigate. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to target the container that encompasses the controls and the player.

```
$('.mute').on('click', function() {
    const $player = $(this).closest('.player-body').find('.player');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to `closest()`, but only if `id` are consistent within the same audio player, could be getting that `id` and use it to target the related audio player:

**Example:**

```
$('.mute').on('click', function()
{
    let id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
    let audPlayer = $('#player_' + id);
});
```